# Passing options to any linux programs from variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort

Desired code:

```
echo "$var" | sort -t/ -k 1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n
```

Case scenario: options to sort arr dynamically created based on condition and stored in variables. How can i pass them.

```
option='-k 1,1n -k2,2n'
echo "$var" | sort -t/ "$option"
```

OR

```
echo "$var" | sort -t/ "$(eval echo "$option")
```

But nothing working.
Throws stray character error

```
sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification ‘ 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n’
```

Comment: For single options with no args, use a variable (and double-quote it).   For multiple options or options with args, use an array (and, again, double-quote it).   Unquoted variables are a problem waiting to happen.  Careless use of `eval` (i.e. without understanding and mitigating the risks) is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `sort` command needs to receive the options as separate parameter strings, i.e. `sort` `-t/` `-k` `1,1n` `-k2,2n` `-k3,3n`.

When you use a double-quoted expansion, like `"$option"`, all the options will be passed as a single string, i.e. `sort` `-t/` `-k 1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n`.

To avoid that, *just don't use quotes* around `$option`:

```
option='-k 1,1n -k2,2n'
echo "$var" | sort -t/ $option
```

The `-k` option to sort can accept the field specification either as part of the same parameter string (`-k2,2n`) or as the next parameter string following the `-k` option (`-k` `1,1n`). It can even accept spaces if the field specification is part of the same parameter string as the option specifier:

```
echo works | sort -t/ "-k 1,1n" -k2,2n -k3,3n
works
```

But even a single whitespace character in the same parameter string after the field specification is not acceptable:

```
echo fails | sort -t/ "-k 1,1n " -k2,2n -k3,3n
sort: stray character in field spec: invalid field specification ‘ 1,1n ’
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a general answer that applies to your question specifically and any other situation where you may want to store command line arguments in a variable before actually using them.

The issue with your code is that when you use `"$option"` on the command line of `sort`, it is a *single* argument.  You could, in this case, solve this by simply removing the quotes and letting the shell split the `$option` string on spaces, tabs, and newlines, and then perform filename globbing on those generated words before calling `sort` with the resulting list.  Doing so would work in your case but would be a less elegant way of solving the issue.

It would be less elegant since it relies on the string `$option` to be correctly split on white spaces and not contain filename globbing patterns.

For a more generic solution, put the options and option-arguments in an array; that way, you may quote each argument that needs it.  The following code assumes that you are using a shell, such as `bash`, which supports arrays.

```bsh
options=( -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n )

sort -t '/' "${options[@]}" <<<"$var"
```

By quoting the expansion of `${options[@]}`, you ensure that each element of the array `options` is expanded as a single field, which means that the shell would expand the `options` array as if all elements were given on the command line individually quoted as arguments to `sort`.

In shells without arrays, use the list of positional parameters instead:

```bsh
set -- -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n

printf '%s\n' "$var" | sort -t '/' "$@"
```

Like with the first code snipped, the quoting of `$@` is essential as it guarantees that each element of the list of positional parameters is expanded intact.  The shell would, here too, expand `"$@"` into a list of fields and provide these as arguments to the `sort` utility.

In any case, you will want to avoid using `echo` to output the value of `$var` as `echo` my modify the data depending on the shell's configuration and the contents of the variable.

See also:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)